# Can't Auto hide a label inside a updatepanel (divPopup screen)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I just want to auto hide a result label after 5 sec. Its perfectly working in normal forms.but not working in Popup screen .Help me to solve this issue.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" ValidationGroup="V2" Style="margin-bottom: 0px" 
                                Text="Export" class="btnNew" OnClick="btnExport_Click" />
                            &nbsp;
                                <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Text="" class="errMsg" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>



function hideuser() {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                var label = document.getElementById('lblResult');
                if (label != null) {
                    label.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }, 5000);
        }


 protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
  string result = objLE.ExportLE(,,,,,,,);
            lblResult.Visible = true;
            lblResult.Text = result;
            System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "Script", "hideuser();", true);
            ClearLEData();
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Val", "ShowExpPopup();", true); //this for retain popup screen every postback occurs

}
```

Comment: i posted answer try that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change your js function as below**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideuser() {

        window.setTimeout(function () {
            var label = document.getElementById('<%= lblResult.ClientID %>');
            if (label != null) {
                label.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
</script>
```

**Change this line**

`var label = document.getElementById('lblResult');`

**to**

**`var label = document.getElementById('<%= lblResult.ClientID %>');`**

Comment: @jithesh - 'upvote' the answer will helps other to find correct solutions. Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Instead of `Visible=false` use `style="display:none"`

```
<asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Text="" 
class="errMsg" style="display:none"></asp:Label>
```

and

`ID` of the server side control will change after rendering into browser. So you need to use it like this

```
var label = document.getElementById('<%= lblResult.ClientID %>');
```